# Scroll bars of scroll pane (having a textArea within it) not appearing properly in java swing GUI

Tags: swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I've created a Swing Frame with the following sequence, JFrame > JPanel > JScrollPane > JTextArea.
I'm using card layout to Load the JPanel into JFrame.

My problem is the scroll bars are not appearing properly(As shown in the image). [image]

My code is as follows:

```
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jTextArea1);


    jTextArea1.setColumns(15);
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jTextArea1.setRows(3);

    JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar();
    verticalScrollBar.setValue(0);
    jTextArea1.setCaretPosition(0);

    jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(632, 425));



//Group Layout
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(
                                    layout.createParallelGroup(
                                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(
                                                    jPanelBottomPanel,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(
                                                    jLabelImageLogoSAGUpgradeUtility,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)

                            )
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(
                                    layout.createParallelGroup(
                                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addGroup(
                                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addContainerGap()
                                                    .addComponent(jPanelStartInstaller,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addContainerGap()
                                                    )
                                            .addGroup(
                                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                            .addGap(10, 10,
                                                                    10)
                                                            .addComponent(
                                                                    jCheckBox1)
                                                            .addGap(0,
                                                                    0,
                                                                    Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                            .addGroup(
                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                            .addContainerGap()
                                                            .addGroup(
                                                                    layout.createParallelGroup(
                                                                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                                                            false)
                                                                            .addGroup(
                                                                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                            .addGap(0,
                                                                                                    0,
                                                                                                    0)
                                                                                            .addComponent(
                                                                                                    jScrollPane1,
                                                                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                                    0,
                                                                                                    Short.MAX_VALUE))
.addGap(5)
                                                                            .addComponent(
                                                                                    jPanel5,
                                                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                                                                    .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
            .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabelImageLogoSAGUpgradeUtility,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(8, 8, 8) 
                            .addComponent(jPanel5,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(
                                    javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jPanelStartInstaller,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                            .addComponent(jPanelBottomPanel,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            ));
```

Comment: FYI: The scroll bars inside a JFileChooser are also not appearing properly, when a JFileChooser is getting opened when a button is clicked...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with those scrollbars. That is just the Nimbus look-and-feel scrollbar (see e.g. [this blog post with Nimbus images](http://www.thectoblog.com/2010/01/nimbus-look-and-feel.html))

Comment: Thanks Robin, if is the look and feel of Nibus, then I need to Change the look and Feel of my code... Thanks a lot, I tried many options for this silly Thing :)...

Comment: On my side, even with Nimbus, all is too nice, as expected. For me I can see one big flaw in your code part, which is this line `jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(632, 425));`. THis line may can cause trouble, don't know though why you want this, but you can add your `JScrollPane` to your `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` at position `CENTER`, that will not cause such issues. I HOPE I had made myself clear :-) BEST OF LUCK :-) Setting sizes for `JComponent`s is the cause for many a weird situations :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your comment,

> *... if is the look and feel of Nibus, then I need to Change the look and Feel of my code...*

You need something this,

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel ("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

Also have a look at this : [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)